# Ceph: EAccess denied when connecting through java

Tags: java, ceph

I am using the below piece of code to talk to Ceph cluster and getting 
EAccess denied exception even though admin user have all privileges *. Any pointers to resolve this issue? I am running the cluster in docker.

Admin privileges:

```
client.admin
    key: AQDVsTJdeF0KExAAd58npeDpnJsXQZwfUBAPMA==
    auid: 0
    caps: [mds] allow
    caps: [mgr] allow *
    caps: [mon] allow *
    caps: [osd] allow *
```

Exception:

> Failed to connect to the Ceph cluster; EACCES: Permission denied
>   (-13): com.ceph.rados.exceptions.RadosException: Failed to connect to
>   the Ceph cluster; EACCES: Permission denied (-13)
>       com.ceph.rados.exceptions.RadosException: Failed to connect to the Ceph cluster; EACCES: Permission denied (-13)
>         at com.ceph.rados.RadosBase.throwException(RadosBase.java:94)
>         at com.ceph.rados.RadosBase.handleReturnCode(RadosBase.java:50)
>         at com.ceph.rados.Rados.connect(Rados.java:160)
>         at com.example.demo.CephClient.main(CephClient.java:20)

Code:

```
Rados cluster = new Rados("admin");
  System.out.println("Created cluster handle.");

  File f = new File("/etc/ceph/ceph.conf");
  cluster.confReadFile(f);
  System.out.println("Read the configuration file.");

  cluster.connect();
  System.out.println("Connected to the cluster.");
```

ceph.conf

```
mon initial members = VirtualBox
mon host = xxx.xxx.x.xxxx
public network = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
cluster network = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
osd journal size = 100
log file = /dev/null
keyring = /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was ceph.client.admin.keyring file permission was with ceph user. I was running the application as root, that’s why got permission denied exception.

After changing the file permission to root. It worked.

```
     sudo chown root:root filepath
```